# Using asterisks as normal characters in Google+ posts?

Tags: google-plus

I'm trying to write a post in Google plus that has a *non-strengthened* word with actual *asterisks* around it?

Using asterisks in a G+ triggers strenghtening of the word, and trying to escape them with `\` just shows the `\*backslashes\*` with the asterisks.

Using `**two**` asterisks around the word does display only one, but also ***strengthens*** the word.

**How do I escape the asterisk characters in a G+ post?**

Comment: See [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/23463/1512).

Comment: Google+ doesn't translate HTML character codes; I don't think that question is applicable @Alex.

Answer (score 3):

It's a really ugly hack, but you can use a [zero width space](http://graphemica.com/200B) to stop the asterisks from being interpreted.

On OS X you can use the `bash` builtin `echo` to generate the unicode character. It's not documented in the man page but BSD `echo` on OS X supports `-e` to enable interpretation of backslash escapes just like it's GNU counterpart. Copy and pasting the string from the Terminal seems to be problematic but you can pipe the output to `pbcopy` to send it directly to the pasteboard.

If you wanted to write `*foobar*` then you could get your patched string like this:

```
echo -en "\xe2\x80\x8b*foobar*" | pbcopy
```

You can use the same workaround to frame your text with the underline character `_`. Maybe someone feels like writing a greasemonkey script to automate this rather clunky process.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... I tried `echo -e "*\xe2\x80\x8bfoobar\xe2\x80\x8b*" | xsel -i --clipboard` and then pasting the clipboard content into a G+ post. The word still gets emphasized. Maybe G+ filters the zero width space from the the input.

Comment: What happens if you paste the string into a text field on another website or a regular text editor? Do you notice having to press arrow keys two times when moving the cursor over the boundary between the asterisks and the word?

Comment: I'm not a linux user, but I see three potential points of failure: `xsel`, clipboard and the browser. Maybe one of those three strips out the zero width spaces before the string reaches the G+ fields.

Comment: Sadly, G+ seems to ignore the zero width space now, so the hack doesn't work anymore. If it's just about expressing common emotions you might wanna check this out: https://gist.github.com/157796

Comment: Google seems to have changed its implementation, but I have found another unicode character which breaks the interpretation of the asterisks (see updated posting).

Comment: Although this is very hacky it did indeed get the job done, thank you.

Comment: I've updated the workaround. Let's see how long this one works ;)

Answer (score 2):

Three in a row `***` will display one. It will be bold, but that seems close enough.

Comment: Does not work for me. `***text***` still appears as `**text**` with "text" in bold.

Answer (score 1):

I only found out so far, that when there is a space between at least one asterisk and the word, it is written normally.

`*asterisk *`or `* asterisk*` would not be bold, but I'm not sure if this solves your problem.

Comment: Well, it's one hackaround, like using ⁎alternate⁎ UTF asterisk character is, but no, it doesn't exactly answer the question since it doesn't get me the result I want.

Comment: This is the solution that I've been using on those rare cases when I want the asterisks to appear.