# How to use a bold asterisk in a Google+ post?

Tags: google-plus

I'm trying to use the asterisk character (*) in a Google Plus post. The problem is that the asterisk character is used in Google+ to make text bold.

`*text*` would make **text**.

In [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25616/using-asterisks-as-normal-characters-in-google-posts), someone manages to use them in regular texts, but I want to put one in bold, like this:

**`this text should be bold but with a * in itself`**

This doesn't seem to work because the * in the bold phrase ends it being bold.

I tried escaping with a `\`, but it didn't work. How can we use a bold asterisk in Google+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it this way, inspired by @w3d's answer, but it was slightly different:

Let's say I wanted to type **`"Hello * worlds!"`**

I had to to it like this in Google+:

`*"Hello ** *worlds!"*`

(Mind that there should be a space between the second and the third asterisk.)

Comment: Ah, you want an asterisk _inside_ a phrase that is already marked up as bold - that wasn't initially clear from your question.

Comment: It was in the second part of my question, you should read them till the end :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any difficulty typing a single asterisk in Google+. A single asterisk should be treated as a literal asterisk (as it is on StackExchange - markdown editor).

To create a **bold** asterisk simply surround it in asterisks, the same as any other phrase. So `***` (3 asterisks) creates a single bold asterisk in the post. However, the difference between a normal and bold asterisk is very subtle on my machine.

[image]

**EDIT:** Although (a bit late) I realise that the question is actually... how to type an asterisk in a phrase that is already emboldened with asterisks, so this might not actually help you!